# Restangular is slow to ask API for data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, restangular

I'm quite new to both javascript and AngularJS, and am trying to figure out how to debug a speed issue I have:

I have a data service defined in my AngularJS app, that calls a JSON RESTful API for the data to populate a `<select>` in a UI-Router view.

When the page loaded for the *first* time, which I simulate by turning off caching in Chrome and doing a shift-F5 to reload the page, the `<select>`'s list of options takes between 8-15 seconds to populate. (Subsequent loads with caching turned on do not get the delays)

Looking at logs, the delay is between getting the html template for the partial for the `ui-view` and hitting the API, so it's not that the API is slow (it's on localhost and the test data set is only four records), it's that there's a **huge** delay between loading the partial and initiating the API call.
I have no errors in the javascript console, nor in any of the server logs.

How can I track down where the delay is coming from?

The Chrome developer tools' network tab show that the vast majority of the time for the XHR retrieval is in the 'waiting' state.

Are there other tools I can use to debug this?

Comment: It looks like a server or network issue. If the server ping is quick, check the query which retrieves the data on the server.

Comment: If you do not find more appropriate tools, WireShark can grab everything.

Comment: To clarify: the delay is AFTER loading the HTML for the partial, but BEFORE the partial triggers the load of data from the API.